# Object required .Interior.Color

Tags: vba

I'm a vba noob so go easy on me, I'm trying to loop through an array and replace the range background color if it matches green.

However I get a object required error in my code, what I'm trying to figure out is why this occurs, I know that I should have an object reference when using interior.color but isn't using 
set loop_target = loop_over.interior.color exactly this? I simply don't understand what's going wrong... Thanks

```
Sub change_color()

Dim loop_over As Variant
Dim loop_target As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim color_range As Long

loop_over = Range("B4:L22")

For i = 1 To UBound(loop_over, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(loop_over, 2)
        Set loop_target = loop_over.Interior.Color
' If statement here -> If interior.color = green Then 
' new interior.color = red or something


    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You are setting a Range (loop_target) with a color (loop_over.interior.color <- and this is incorrect usage as well).  Are you trying to set the loop_target range with specific color?

Comment: You should put `Set` in front of `loop_over = ...` like you did later for a different variable. Objects require the Set syntax. Also not sure why you are assigning a color to a range.

Comment: I started with setting the set on loop_over, but I get a type mismatch at the beginning of the loop ( for i = 1 ), how do I execute the loop in this case?

Why I put the set on the color was because I wanted to use the loop_target when i loop

Comment: Oh you are trying to read the range as an array not a range (based on your loops. I'm not a fan of the Variant type when you know at design time what type it will be. But if you want an array you are correct in NOT needing `Set` but I think you will need to put `()` after `Dim loop_over` above.

Comment: You guys put me in the right direction. I have modified the code now to.
`code` Sub change_color()

Dim loop_over As Range
Dim loop_target() As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim color_range As Long

Set loop_over = Range("B4:L22")
loop_target = loop_over.Interior.Color

For i = 1 To UBound(loop_target, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(loop_target, 2)
        If loop_target Is RGB(0, 128, 0) Then
        loop_target = "RGB(255, 0, 0)"

                

    Next j
Next i

End Sub
`code`
I like it more to declare the end type at design. But tell me, what type should one have for the loop_target?

Comment: When you use `loop_over = Range("B4:L22")` then loop_over only get the *values* of the cells in the range: you cannot examine the elements in the array to find out other properties of the cells in the range.

Comment: loop_over.Interior.Color can be stored as a long but not as a Range. Store it in color_Range NOT loop_target and without the Set keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub change_color()

Dim c as Range, rng As Range, clr as long

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("B4:L22")

    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
            clr = rng.Cells(i,j).Interior.Color
            If clr = vbGreen Then
                rng.Cells(i,j).Interior.Color = vbRed
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I will study this code more deeply. 

But is execution-time not faster if you put it in an array? 
I noticed that you had rng as range only, rng is thus not an array? I thought you could only loop through areas of ranges if they were arrays.

Comment: If you only want to access *values* from a range and that range is large, then loading the values into an array and looping over that array is definitely the way to go.  Here however you're not interested in just the values (since you need to be able to check the fill color), so you need to work directly with the Range itself.

Comment: Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can keep it simple using `For Each Cell` in your Range and Use `Cell.Interior.Color`

```
Sub change_color()    
Set MyRng = Range("B4:L22")
  For Each Cell In MyRng.Cells
    Debug.Print Cell.Interior.Color & "-" & Cell.Value
    If (Cell.Interior.Color = 456752) Then Cell.Interior.Color = 1234567
  Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you too. That was a quick way.